# How to avoid "null" with match()

Tags: javascript, null, match

I am using a method to find Media Queries in code.

```
function checkMediaQueries() {
    var css = cssText;
    var patt1 = /@media/gi;
    countMQ = css.match(patt1).length;

    if (countMQ == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It all works fine when it finds some Media Queries. But when the method cant find any, it wont return anything because countMQ is null. I know the problem, but cant find a solution for it.

How can i avoid this result and make my method return false instead?

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.length`, as null has no length

```
var countMQ = css.match(patt1);
```

and check for truthy, not `0`

```
if (countMQ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

or even `null`, if you wan't to be more specific

```
if (countMQ === null) {
```

or simpler

```
function checkMediaQueries() {
    return cssText.match(/@media/gi) ? true : false;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DFWc4/)

Comment: Thanks.And how can i handle this when i actually need the amount of matches? Like i want to return something else when i can find e.g. 3 Media Queries?

Comment: match will return the number of matches, so you can just use that instead of the boolean

Comment: Yep, but then I have the problem that there is an error when there is no match.

Comment: match will return the number of matches **or** null, so you can just check for null, if it's not null, the length will give you the number of matches.

Comment: Thanks, but i am not sure how i can realize this in Code, do u have an example or something for me?